# How to write stream of lines, separated by delimiters, to separate files?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a stream of lines (output of `schtasks /query /XML`), containing multiple XML files concatenated together and separated by comments of the form

```xml
<!-- \Microsoft\Windows\WS\WSTask -->
```

I would like to write this output to separate files, each containing one XML file named after the delimiter.

Comment: Can certainly be done, but there are a few considerations you need to make first - do you need to maintain the task folder hierarchy when you export the definitions to file? How do you want to name the definition files?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The naming is not that important. E.g. you could replace the backslashes with underscores (or any other placeholder) and write all files to the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to join all lines, strip the first and last line, split on the comments (retaining them), then iterate through the array in pairs using the first item of the pair as the file name and the second item as the XML document to save. This should save all of your tasks to the current path:

```
$tasks = schtasks /query /XML
[xml[]]$XMLTasks = ([string[]]$tasks) -join "`n" -replace '\<\/Tasks\>$' -split "(\<!--.*?-->)"|select -skip 1|%{$_.trim()}
For($i=0;$i -lt $XMLTasks.Count;$i=$i+2){
    $SavePath = join-path $pwd.path ($XMLTasks[$i].'#comment'.Trim(' \').Replace('\','_')+'.xml')
    $XMLTasks[$i+1].Save($SavePath)
}
```